# Best method for sealing underneath basement window sill?

Tags: basement, windows, sealing, caulking, weatherstripping

There is a large gap underneath the bottom sill of the window, that is currently caulked when the house was built.

I would like to strengthen the waterproofing here. I'm thinking backer rod with Vulkem 116 caulking.

Would this be the best way?

Here is a picture of the window, it's the channel underneath the sill.
[image: window]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Window and door spray foam a good solution for this exterior section underneath a window?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/114325/window-and-door-spray-foam-a-good-solution-for-this-exterior-section-underneath)

Comment: "backer rod with Vulkem 116 caulking" yes. If there's a better product than that, lemme know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have built both residential and commercial buildings. Every scenario such as this we use expansion foam which can be found at most hardware stores. Then once hardened, carefully scrape back some to leave room for any type of silicone caulk or whatever you choose for a finished look.

Comment: It is a low expansion foam, as in Great Stuff window and door?

Comment: Yes that is correct. http://www.homedepot.com/p/GREAT-STUFF-16-oz-Window-and-Door-Insulating-Foam-Sealant-248312/100068117